# PrawnPDF Flip Entire PDF

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, printing, prawn

I'm using Prawn PDF to create a label that I send to a label printer, but the label prints upside down. This is important as the shipping labels we use come with some print already on it. The setup I'm using (an iPad through a Lantronix xPrintServer to a Zebra Printer) won't allow me to flip it using the drivers.

So I'm wanting to know if there is a way using Prawn (or even just Rails) to flip the entire document (which contains 2+ pages) so it prints out correctly on the labels. The order of the pages isn't essential.

Comment: Can you flip the blank labels before you put them into the machine?

Comment: They are on a roll, so flipping them is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used Prawn lately, but I'm pretty sure using the [`rotate`](http://prawnpdf.org/docs/0.11.1/Prawn/Graphics/Transformation.html#method-i-rotate) method at the top of your code will work. You'll  just need to either set the origin to the center of the page, or use `translate` to reposition the content after rotation. Page 29 in the [manual](http://prawnpdf.org/manual.pdf) (PDF) has some example code.

Comment: That's works for the most part. It seems like Prawn doesn't like it when I do that with a multiple page table, but I think I can get around that.

Answer (score 0):

You could save the pdf to a file and then use the awesome `pdftk` to rotate the saved pdf, then send the amended version.

https://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-cli-examples/

EDIT - pdftk is not a library/plugin/gem, or any kind of Ruby for that matter.  It's a command line tool which you would use like this, in your controller, replacing your current "generate and send pdf" code.

```
#instead of sending the pdf straight to the user, save it to a file
#i'm not sure how to do this in prawn but it can't be difficult

#rotate the original to a new file
`pdftk /path/to/original.pdf cat 1-endsouth output /path/to/rotated.pdf`

#you could test whether the rotated file exists here as an error-check

#then use send_file to send the rotated one as the response. 
send_file "/path/to/rotated.pdf", :type => "application/pdf"
```

Comment: I was hoping to use an "on the fly" method. Really don't want to use another library/plugin/gem.